# Java Valid identifier

Tags: java, identifier

I am preparing for my school test and i have a Simple question:

```
Which of the following is a VALID identifier?
a. this
b. that
c. int
d. double
e. not of the above
```

I think the answer is b.that do you agree and why?

Comment: Do you know basics of Java?

Comment: Why do you think the answer is B?

Comment: Hint: some words are *reserved* ones. For instance, you can't call a variable *class*

Comment: How about testing it? Declare a variable with each of these names, and see which compile and which not, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: Funny thing is that SO actually kind of highlighted the correct answers in blue.. as they are part of `code`

Comment: Specifications of Java identifiers [JLS 3.8 Identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

Comment: there is a good question hidden somewhere deep inside this question, hidden under the fact that this is homework and that it is put in a multiple choice form. But the question "what makes a valid Java identifier?" would be a good one.

Comment: @Phantomazi Actually it highlighted the incorrect answers in blue.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer:

> a. that

In java you are not allowed to use keywords as identifiers.

> this

is a keyword for pointing to current object

> int

is a keyword for primitive integer type

> double

is a keyword for primitive double type.

P.S: You are not supposed to ask questions, without research and efforts.
I am not supposed to promote such questions by answering...:)

Comment: hey thank you very much, a little confuse with ton of information available online. just need some clear guide line